# Yet Another HttpClient / Async Deadlock

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I've been banging my head on this for hours, and I've thrown my hands up in the air on this one. As far as I can tell, I've encountered a deadlock surrounding HttpClient and Async.

The goal is for a series of unrelated Posts to all get fired off in rapid succession, wait for them all to get done, and then construct a document from the resultset. The program has a WPF UI, and this is triggered by button:

```
private async void Generate_Suite_BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var suiteBuilder = new SuiteBuilder();
    await Task.Run(() => suiteBuilder.worker_Run());
}
```

That triggers the worker_Run(), which has some switch logic, and eventually gets down to hitting SendFiles() which has a Parrallel.Foreach, since the sending of the files doesn't need to be sequential, and are unrelated to eachother:

```
private bool SendFiles()
{
    var result = Parallel.ForEach(_InfoCollection, SendFile);
    return result.IsCompleted;
}
```

Each of those (in the parallel), is awaited in SendFile(), which also has some switch logic, based on what we're sending, but ultimately boils down to:

```
var result = await Client.SendMessage ( vars );
results.Add(result.MessageId, result.StatusCode, result.HttpReason);
```

Here's the HttpClient portion in SendMessage():

```
public async Task<Result> SendMessage(vars)
{
    var soapResponse = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", soapAction);
        Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Timeout);
        var content = new StringContent(soapRequest, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);
        var post =  await Client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var response = post.Content;
        result.StatusCode = post.StatusCode;
        result.HttpReason = post.ReasonPhrase;
        var sResponse = await response.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        soapResponse.Load(sResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Catch logic
    }
}
```

I can see the request and response passing back and forth with Fiddler, but I'm having trouble line-by-line debugging, since as soon as I hit the PostAsync, VS flips out and continues all the way to the end of the program, skipping all breakpoints. Meanwhile, the request times out with a TaskCanceledException, long after the code that should come afterwards already has completed.

I've looked a dozens of question & answers here on SO, and elsewhere, but they're just not quite helping find the problem. Most seem to center around the liberal sprinkling of ".ConfigureAwait(false)" on Async calls, but it doesn't really seem to have any effect.

Comment: Can you post the entire method or all of the code related? I don't feel like there's enough here for me to help although others may be able to.

Comment: Something seems missing here. Why isn't `suiteBuilder.worker_Run()` awaited. Can you post more of that method?

Comment: As @MichaelPuckettII commented there is not enough information. `.ConfigureAwait(false);` calls  hint on calling bulk of the code from UI thread that does not align at all with `await Task.Run(() => suiteBuilder.worker_Run());`... Please read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] code accordingly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've edited the question to include more detail, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @JSteward I think it's appropriately awaited? I've since edited the question to include more code on context, perhaps I omitted it by accident.

Comment: What return type is `worker_Run`? If it's void then that's your problem. `SendFiles` should be `Task<bool>` and `worker_Run` should be `Task` ro `Task<T>`.

Comment: Also note that `Parallel.Foreach` is not intended for an async delegate it takes an `Action<T>` parameter. Using an async delegate will result in an un-awaitable `async void`

Comment: @JSteward Yup, worker_run() was void, but I'm not clear on how to get SendFiles() to return Task<bool> as the Parrallel.ForEach doesn't seem to play well.

Comment: Hm, that's troublesome, since I'd like the UI to not hang while I work, but there's plenty of work to be done, and serial processing of the requests is pretty slow.

Comment: Since your operation is ultimatly IO bound you shouldn't be using `Parallel.Foreach` any way. Use a basic `LINQ Select` over your files collection and make everything async all the way up to event handler. Since your async operation will naturally `yield` the `Select` will run them in parallel and then simply `await` them with a `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: Ian Moriarty, please re-read [MCVE] guidance. It is generally impossible to help with debugging questions when half of the code is not shown and such questions are rarely useful for future visitors. So far code shown is very strange mix of fragments using somewhat incompatible `Task.Run`, `Parrallel.ForEach` and `async` methods. It would not be surprising that code not shown has plenty of `.Result` calls (without `await`). As @JSteward said it is very likely you need just call multiple async methods at the same time and than await `Task.WhenAll`...

Answer (score 2):

So, with the help of @JSteward in the comments, he pointed out that `async` and `Parrallel.ForEach` aren't well suited to working together, since return types of `void` when dealing with async should be avoided.

He recommended that I use Async only, from the top (Button Click) to the bottom (Message Send), and that worked out. Credit to him for the guidance.

This link was helpful in explaining why this was the case: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/jj991977)

SendFiles ended up looking something like this:

```
private async Task<bool> SendFiles()
{
    var result = _InfoCollection.Select(SendFile);
    await Task.WhenAll(result).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return true;
}
```

All the other methods went `async`, with appropriate `awaits`, and return types of `Task` or `Task<T>`.